# I want to call a Javascript function from Android Button Click but some time getting syntax error

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have written a code which calls a javascript function on web view page on clicking a button in  Android App. But in most of the case it is working properly but sometimes it gives the following error "I/chromium: [INFO: CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",
Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error
Here is my code for calling javascript function

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //EditText textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        sender_template = result;
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: compose('"+sender_template+"');void(0);");
    }
```

Comment: `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: compose('"+sender_template+"');");` Or `mWebView.loadUrl("compose('"+sender_template+"');");`

Comment: Have you escaped the input (`sender_template`)? Meaning there could be unescaped single quotes inside the string and causing problems. For instance if it contained `hello ' world` your line could end up being `compose('hello ' world');void(0);`